# Why is the initial string being ignored when using += in a function in powershell?

Tags: string, powershell, concatenation

I am using the += operator to add to an initial string in a PowerShell function. This is resulting in the initial string being removed. If I write out the operation without using the += operator, I get the expected result.

```
$intro1 = "This intro piece gets deleted:"
$intro2 = "This intro piece does not get deleted:"

Function Test-String{
  $names = @("name1","name2")

  If( $names ) {
    ForEach($name in $names) { $intro1 += $name }
    ForEach($name in $names) { $intro2 = $intro2 + $name }

    Write-Host "intro1: $intro1"
    Write-Host "intro2: $intro2"
  }
}

Test-String
```

Result:

```
intro1: name1name2
intro2: This intro piece does not get deleted:name1name2
```

What is the cause of this behavior?

Comment: This is a [known issue with scopes](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11297) (also [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4312)). That said, the behavior for this script is different between PowerShell 5.x and 7.x -- one comment in #11297 seems to imply all versions of PowerShell since 3.0 should exhibit the same behavior, but that's not the case, so this may be a separate problem, or a different aspect of the same.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a scope issue you can fix it this way:

```
$intro1 = @("This intro piece gets deleted:")
$intro2 = @("This intro piece does not get deleted:")

Function Test-String{
  $names = @("name1","name2")

  If( $names ) {
    ForEach($name in $names) { $Script:intro1 += $name }
    ForEach($name in $names) { $Script:intro2 = $Script:intro2 + $name }

    Write-Host "intro1: $Script:intro1"
    Write-Host "intro2: $Script:intro2"
  }
}

Test-String
```

Note: forcing the initial values to an array gets you the output like this:

```
intro1: This intro piece gets deleted: name1 name2
intro2: This intro piece does not get deleted: name1 name2
```

-- VS --

```
intro1: This intro piece gets deleted:name1name2
intro2: This intro piece does not get deleted:name1name2
```